# Expectation and definition of variance - notational question.

Tags: probability, notation

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$

I have someone who writes expectation as being $\E(X - \E(X))^2$

Is it possible for this to be notationally correct?

I would expect to rather read $\E((X - \E(X))^2)$ for instance, if not $\E[(X - \E(X))^2]$

I've encountered this in a university lecture, but I was wondering if there were an educational tradition in some probability texts which would see this written in this way.

Comment: Normally of linear operator, we don't write the brackets, i.e. $\mathbb E[X]$ is often written as $\mathbb E X$. For $\mathbb E(X-\mathbb E(X))^2$, it's definitely $\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E(X))^2]$. Btw, you have that $Var(X)=\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E(X))^2]=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2$.

Comment: @Surb or sometimes written as $\mathbb E(X-\mathbb E X)^2$ corresponding to $\mathbb E[(X-\mathbb E[X])^2]$

Comment: @Henry yes, but where is is such a rule of precedence even established that $\E$ has such weak binding compared to other operators?

Answer (score 1):

The expectation of a random variable is defined via an integral and integration is linear, hence expectation is linear—indeed, it is of a class of objects called *linear operators*.  That is
$$ \mathbb{E}[X+Y]
= \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]. $$
When we study linear operators, we typically omit the parentheses.

As a basic example, think about linear algebra.  An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is a way of representing a linear operator.  That is, we can think of $A$ as a function
$$ A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, $$
which acts on elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ via matrix multiplication.  If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we can think of $A$ a function acting on $x$ and write $A(x)$ or $A[x]$, or we can think of $A$ as a matrix that acts by matrix multiplication on the column vector $x$ and write $Ax$.  The notation here is unambiguous, so we typically omit the braces.

We adopt a similar approach to notation when we deal with linear operators in general.  That is, if $T : X \to Y$ is a linear operator ($T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, plus the necessary hypotheses on the spaces $X$ and $Y$ (basically, they are topological vector spaces), plus some other technical conditions), then we typically write $Tx$ rather than $T(x)$.

Because expectation is linear, it is reasonable to adopt the same notation, and write $\mathbb{E}X$ rather than $\mathbb{E}[X]$ or $\mathbb{E}(X)$, which is often done.  That is (to finally answer your question), it is common to see notation such as
$$ \mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2. $$
Because it is possible that this notation could be ambiguous, one could be forgiven (or even lauded!) for more explicitly writing
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ (X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2 \right]. $$
On the other hand, in the particular example that you have given, the expression gives the variance; that is
$$ \mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2 =: \operatorname{Var}(X). $$
Because this is such a common expression, it is even more reasonable to assume that the reader is familiar with the notation, and is willing to accept some slightly more terse notation.